# Firestore deserialize unkown enum type

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Lets say i have the following object

```
User {
   gender: Gender = MALE
   age: Int = 0
}
```

and i stored this in firestore. now assume the Gender is a enum as follows

```
enum class Gender {
  MALE,
  FEMALE
}
```

if i would now say i want to extend the `Gender` enum with `OTHER` and store this in firestore and an earlier version of my app wants to read this from firestore it does not know the gender `OTHER`. if i would the read form a colleciton and call `snapshot.toObject<Gender>()` this would lead to an error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Could not find enum value of User for value "OTHER" (found in field 'gender')`.

How would i say if this happens that i would choose for example `MALE` by default and the exception would not occur. since i cannot override the `valueOf()` function of an enum that is used by the `toObject()` function i have completely no clue how todo this. any suggestions?

Comment: you might not be able to avoid the exception, but maybe you can use it ? can't you add a try catch and if the exception occurs, default to your value ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I also thought of that but i assume that if the serialization throws an exception and I will have no objects where i can set my enum default type by hand.

Comment: Can please show us, how do you store the value of "MALE", in Firestore? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: For backwards compatibility you probably can't, you would have to create a new field which newer versions of your app will know how to work with.
I would suggest using a string and converting to enum yourself.

Comment: You can follow this issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1418